# Why does the cloud in a straight line as if someone draw a line in the sky with a straight edge?

Tags: thermodynamics, visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation

My cousin took one of the pictures below (the middle) in the evening in BKK and she confirmed that she took it with her phone. I've been trying to explain it. I thought it had to do with hot air and the buildings. At first I thought where there was no cloud the air was hotter (which dispersed the cloud away). All those buildings used AC so they absorbed the heat from the sun all day, but on the street between the building not much heat(from the sun) was absorbed so this heat was reflected up into the air and dispersed the cloud. But looking at the wider picture,  this explanation still makes no sense. It's something in the sky!!! Can anyone come up with a good explanation?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Those are crepuscular rays, regarding which there are a number of questions on this site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do sunbeams diverge even though the sun is much more than a few kilometers away?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/154951/why-do-sunbeams-diverge-even-though-the-sun-is-much-more-than-a-few-kilometers-a)

Comment: For more cloud shadows, poke around Atmospheric Optics, starting [here](https://www.atoptics.co.uk/atoptics/clshad.htm) or [here](https://www.atoptics.co.uk/fz931.htm).

Comment: We appreciate that pictures of this phenomenon can look very beautiful, but **this thread is not the place to post them**.

Answer (score 10):

The Sun is so low to the horizon that it’s illuminating the high, wispy clouds from *underneath*. Where it’s dark, something (probably a cumulus cloud) is blocking that light.

The thin cloud in the resulting shadow is still there if you look closer, but it’s much harder to see because it’s not illuminated.

The line is so straight because Sun's light is just barely grazing the bottom of the wispy clouds.  That line is the geometric projection of only the bit of the cloud that's throwing the shadow at just the right altitude.

Comment: I don't think the clouds are being illuminated from underneath --- see [here](https://www.atoptics.co.uk/fz931.htm) for a photograph and sketch of a similar effect.